# Fix Labview Alt-Tab behaviour with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, labview, alt-tab

Did anyone try to fix the way Labview interferes with normal `Alt-Tab` behaviour using Autohotkey?

`Alt-Tab` inside Labview puts all non-labview windows to the end of the list.

So if you have just alt-tabbed to labview window from your browser it takes

(2 × *number_of_currently_open_labview_projects* -1)

keystrokes to get back.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea. I find that functionality annoying and there doesn't appear to be an easy fix anywhere on the web. Here's my script. Two quick notes:

- I had a lot of trouble re-mapping Alt-Tab. If that's critical you can try starting [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/58396-alttab-remap/) for help.
- To my knowledge it's not possible to get rid of the "screen flicker" because Windows requires some delay between keystrokes.

Note: to adapt this code for various Windows - look up the "ahk_class" using the Window Spy tool included in the AutoHotkey [installer](http://ahkscript.org/) .

Code

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future 
AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#NoTrayIcon 
#SingleInstance force

SetTitleMatchMode 2 ;partial search mode
#IfWinActive vi
#q:: ;there were issues mapping to Alt+Tab

CountOfVIs := -1
WinGet, id, list,ahk_class LVDChild,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
CountOfVIs := CountOfVIs +1
}

msgbox, # of VIs open: %CountOfVIs% ;when I remove this it doesn't work - must be an AHK thing

Send {Alt down}
Loop,%CountOfVIs%
{
Send {tab}
Sleep,50 ;if this is too low it doesn't work
} 
Send {Alt up}
```

Comment: Good start! It doesn't count the vis well though. I have one vi file open (that is 2 windows: FP and BD) - it says I have three.

Comment: Should be easy to track down - just run a WinGet and see what's there. I'm counting by looking for vi in the WIndow title, but can amend the code if you have something else showing up. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm

Comment: In my experiments `ahk_class LVDChild` proved to be reliable enough

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found an [article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/260723/) related to this problem, but unfortunately it is in Russian.

It references the following [blog](http://axil.github.io/fix-alt-tab-in-labview.html) with a python script (+autohotkey mapping) that seems to be solving the problem without the "screen flicker".